# How to add wordpress image caption to woocommerce archive product (shop) page but not to the single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce 2.4.4 and Wordpress 4,3, I have read many suggestions for making changes to woocommerce shop page; however I cannot find anyone who addresses my specific request. I have limited understanding of Woocommerce; however I have been trying to solve my request, but to no avail.

I want to display the wordpress caption field for each image in the wordpress media library in my woocommerce shop page but not on the individual products.

I have made changes to my child theme, Deli (A woocommerce theme) functions.php . I added the following to the child functions.php.

```
function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

$attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
return array(
    'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 

true ),
    **'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,**
    'description' => $attachment->post_content,
    'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
    'src' => $attachment->guid,
    'title' => $attachment->post_title
);
}
```

I believe the field that has the image caption is 'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,  as defined above.

I am trying to edit the Woocommerce Archive-product.php but do not know what to add or where to add it in the archive-product.php.

Answer (score 1):

Hey as per your requirement have tried a code which might help you in your case or you can customize it further as per your request.

Add the following code to your Theme's functions.php.

**Note: Its better to create a child theme first and do your customization in it so that the customization won't get overwritten when the theme updates.**

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','wdm_shop_image_caption_func', 10,3 );
function wdm_shop_image_caption_func($attr, $attachment, $size){
    if($size=='shop_single'){
    unset($attr['title']);
    }
    elseif($size=='shop_catalog'){
    $attr['title']=$attr['alt'];
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

[image]

Make sure that you set Caption for every Product's Images.

[image]

Comment: I am changing my approach because I had so many challenges trying to change woocommerce shop page.

Comment: My new approach is to change my child function.php and get the image meta data from there and display the image with meta data (of which image caption is extremely important to me.

Comment: As a sideways confirmation, I'm using the Divi theme, and its Carousel implementation automatically displays the caption. So instead of causing the archive page to be displayed, I just have a custom page displaying the carousel. I added html for a "Buy Now" button link at the end of the caption text, and that simply links to the single product page. Works just as @WisdmLabs describes.